# function.session-start issue using WordPress e-commerce plugin

Tags: php

Trying to get an e-commerce plug-in to work in WordPress. Totally fresh install; this is my second try. Same error message "line 17." I've read the other posts which suggest moving "session_start();" to the top of the file. Tried this. "Fixed" error message, but "add to cart" function of the plugin fails once I try the fix everyone recommends. Am not super great with php, css, html am great. Sorry not sure I know how to add code to this post. Thanks!
ERROR MESSAGES:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/15/6189915/tmp/sess_7io7u6o8n5lsn4hlbrd95kbud5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/.../wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 17
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /.../wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php:17) in /home/.../plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 17
```

THE CODE:

```
<?php

// Left Overs

$wpsc_currency_data = array();

$wpsc_title_data    = array();



/**

 * wpsc_core_load_session()

 *

 * Load up the WPEC session

 */

function wpsc_core_load_session() {

    if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) )

        $_SESSION = null;

    if ( ( !is_array( $_SESSION ) ) xor ( !isset( $_SESSION['nzshpcrt_cart'] ) ) xor ( !$_SESSION ) )

        session_start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) value from php.ini is incorrect.  The path it seems to be trying to use is  `/var/chroot/home/content/15/6189915/tmp/`.

PHP is saying this path doesn't exist in your first error message.

Can you confirm if that directory exists?  If not, create it if you can, or set the session save path prior to calling session_start(), or ask your host to fix the issue for you.

Comment: Cool, thanks am on hold with GoDaddy right now. This has been going on for a while. They moved my files to a new server and it "broke" another install as well... same error message!

Comment: Resolved. Totally was a hosting issue. Might have looked into it myself, but have no access to my absolute directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when trying to resolve the same issue. For anyone else that finds this question like I did here is what worked for me. I am running my site on Godaddy which seems to be the case with most people... Hope it helps

As @Drew010 already said:

---

- You need to edit your php5.ini file. If you don't already have one then create one and place it in the root of your website directory (so in the case of a Wordpress install, this will be the folder where your wp-config.php file will be). Then add the following to the file and save:

  session.save_path = /tmp

---

- Next you will need to create a folder called tmp, and place it in the
  same folder as the php5.ini file.

---

- Lastly you will need to find the wpsc-constants.php file and edit the line:

  session_start();

  to read:

  session_save_path("/tmp"); session_start();

  remove any while space before  tags, as well before the session_start();